# Search for exact match of parameters mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am searching in below table for size 2. But after return of results I am getting two rows having product id's 1,2. As because product id 1,2 contains size 2. But product with id 2 contains other sizes also. That is 3 and 5. And I am looking only for size 2.

So what exactly I want is final results will contain only one row as product id 1. As because I am only searching for size 2.

So how should I achieve this.

[image]

Comment: Nice question @Yogesh please  try my answer.

Comment: Thanks @Bibhudatta Sahoo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After altos of research i got the solution
Try this query:-

```
 SELECT * FROM `product` 
 where size in ('2','3','5') and
 product_id not in (select product_id FROM `product` where size not in ('2','3','5'))
```

In place of `('2','3','5')` you have to pass your ids like this only.
    According to your data this query will produce out put as

[image]

I thing it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with `group by` and `having`:

```
select product_id
from t
group by product_id
having min(size) = max(size) and min(size) = 2;
```

Comment: Thanks this works if I am searching only for size 2. But If I am looking for size 2,3,5 then I would get two rows as product id 1,2. Then how this can be possible ?

Comment: @Yogeshk . . . Then you have a different question and it should be asked as a *question* not a *comment*.  Revising your current question would be rude.  It would invalidate any answers, drawing downvotes to them.

Comment: Yeah. Sorry for this. But I want same results to be done in same query. Thats why I asked in comment.